# synchronize threads with semaphore in c language

Tags: c

This code is create 20 threads. Each thread generate a random string and sorting it in alpabet manner.  What I want is synchronized result like below

'##########Thread #1 starting ##########'

'##########Thread #2 starting ##########'

'##########Thread #3 starting ##########'

......

'##########Thread #19 starting ##########'

and follows the thread critical section like below

[0] abcdcdf -> abcdefg

[1] abcdcdf -> abcdefg

[2] abcdcdf -> abcdefg

.....

[19] abcdcdf -> abcdefg

The order of the thread number can be mixed but it
must not be omitted or overlaped. And each section
should be divided(Thread#n starting and [n] abvdffd -> abcddes)

what component should be inplemented in this code?
It would be very generous of you if show me the upgraded code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define num_thread 20

char str[11];   //Global variable shared to threads                                                            
void *thread_work(void *tid);//Main body of Thread Working
void generate_str(int n);       //Create a random character array
void str_sort(int n);   //Sorting the char array alpabetically
void check_sort(void);
void print_time(struct timespec *myclock);    
void print_time_start(struct timespec *myclock);  
void print_time_end(struct timespec *myclock);
sem_t my_sem;

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid[num_thread];
    int ret; 
    int t;
    struct timespec myclock[2];
    srand(time(NULL));     //changes string value of each execution of program
    ret = sem_init(&my_sem, 0, 1);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &myclock[0]);
    print_time_start(myclock);  
        for(t=0; t<num_thread; t++)
        ret = pthread_create(&tid[t], NULL, thread_work, (void *)&t);

    for(t=0; t<num_thread; t++)
        ret = pthread_join(tid[t], NULL);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &myclock[1]);
    print_time_end(myclock);

    sem_destroy(&my_sem);
    return 0;
}

void *thread_work(void *t)
{
    int n = *((int *)t);
    struct timespec myclock[2]; 
    printf("########## Thread #%d starting ########## \n",n);

    sem_wait(&my_sem);  //Entry Section

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &myclock[0]);   //Critical Section Start  
    generate_str(n);
    str_sort(n);
    check_sort();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &myclock[1]);
    print_time(myclock);              //Critical Section End

    sem_post(&my_sem);  //Exit Section
```

}

Comment: What did you find while debugging?  What happens that should not happen?  What does not happen that should happen?

Comment: sorry;; I will write more clearly next time;; Thank you for you to spend your valuable time on my code

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following changes

1. `#include<unistd.h> //for usleep(1);`
2. `for(t=0 ; t < num_thread; t++)

   {

   //pass the value of t insted of address

   ret = pthread_create(&tid[t], NULL, thread_work, (void *)t);

   usleep(1); //sleep is required to maintain the order of thread start;

   }`
3. `int n = (int )t; //insted of int n = *((int *)t);`, if you pass address of t in pthread_create, by the time the thread get schedule the value of t will be changed by main thread.
4. lock the semaphore, `sem_wait(&my_sem)` before thread creation loop and unlock (`sem_post(&my_sem)`) it after thread creation loop in `main()`.